# Range python, 8 answers instead of 1

Tags: python, range

So i have made this program in python, it works 100%, everything is good, but in the output i get 8 answers (because n=8) , how can i set the range so that i just get the 8th answer instead of 8 answers.

[image: Program]

output:

What is the lowerlimit?:0

What is the upperlimit?:5

How many division intervals do you want?:8

The surface under the line is 0.15

The surface under the line is 1.37

The surface under the line is 5.49

The surface under the line is 15.26

The surface under the line is 34.33

The surface under the line is 67.29

The surface under the line is 119.63

The surface under the line is 197.75

> > > 

Comment: Inside the for loop: `if i == 7: print("Your answer")`

Comment: mode `print()` outside your `for-loop`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: yeah i did that , but it did not take it as a code, thats why i did it with a ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an if condition before the print statement as below.

```
for i in range(n):
   xi = xi + dx
   Sum = Sum+f(xi)
   if i==n-1:
     print("The surface under the line is ",%(Sum*dx))
```

Comment: Thank you! , that is what i looked for

Answer (score 0):

Move the `print` statement outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last number, in this case, the sum, it's as simple as printing it after the summation has completed...

```
dx = float ((b-a)/n)
xi = 1
sum = 0
for i in range(n)
     xi+dx
     sum = sum +f(xi)
print(f"your message{sum*dx}")
```

Also, if it's always going to be the nth number you want to print, or every n numbers, you can use a simple condition check in the loop, and print whenever that happens.

```
dx = float ((b-a)/n)
xi = 1
sum = 0
for i in range(n):
     xi+dx
     sum = sum +f(xi)
        if i == 8:
            print(f"your message{sum*dx}")
```

It's likey the confusion here is due to a misunderstanding of how indentation is working/how the code flows. [Here are](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) the docs if you're inclined to look into it!

Answer (score 0):

```
if i==7:
    #do print
```

or append all the values of `(Sum*dx)` then print whatever the index of value you need. 
like `list.append(Sum*dx)`

Or print the value `(Sum*dx)` outside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you want but if you only want the 8th output (in your example The surface under the line is 197.75) just add the line

```
if i == n-1
```

before the print command.
And use better names for variables and functions